# Moved Website to Azure App Service and getting hit with 401

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, azure-web-app-service, http-status-code-401

Front end project designed in React with node.js and pushed to an app service.

Back end API in C# needed upgraded from .net core 2.2 to .net6 in order to be compatiable on app service.

Quick test of basic functionality of the site all works well and handed over to the testers to find any bugs.

They both complained of being logged out multiple times. I looked into the failures in the appinsights and was able to diagonise the environment variable wasnt setup in configuration in the API app service so it was pointing to the wrong URL to say who the author of the JWT token was.

Resolved this and they went back to testing.
Second round of testing, Both testers complained about being logged out once during testing.

I checked failures on the app insight and there is a 401 response and an exception which matches up with one of the testers timeline.

The security token expiry message:

```
IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo (UTC): '8/15/2023 11:22:29 PM', Current time (UTC): '8/15/2023 11:22:30 PM'.
```

So the JWT was expired and it triggered the 401 which logged out the user, right?

But my issue with this is the logic for JWT and resfresh token and updating the cache and header on the front end is well tested and working on current live enviroenemtn on IIS on a VM.

The second tester didnt have a secuirty token expiry exception but they did have 401 response listed as a failure.

I suppose I am asking for advice on how to replicate this and find this issue.
Iv added extra logs temp recording JWT and refresh tokens each time the cache and header on the front end has been updated from the API (which is whenever a user logs in, and then by an expiry date on  every 20 mins which uses a refresh token to post back to the APi to retrieve a new JWT token) which is working and I dropped the timer to 5 mins and have tested the site multiple times past the JWT expiry time and everything is working.

So the next time it happens I can compare the expired time in secuirty token error message in app singhts against the logged jwt expiry times in the temp table to see if the header has been updated since then

New token is being updated and sent to the front end where the header is updated with and used to post to the api controllers.

I can't seem to replicate these 401 errros. Does anyone have any ideas please or anything I am unaware of about moving to app service, regarding auth etc...?